# Implementing Interface in Method

Tags: java, class, variables, interface, implementation

Hello I was assigned to do the following,

> Write a new Java interface called DelimitedTextIO with the following methods:
>
> > o String toText(char delimiter) 
> >         - This method returns a String containing all the data of the
> >         implementing class as text and with each element separated by the
> >         provided delimiter.
> >
> > o void toObject(Scanner input) 
> >         - This method uses the provided Scanner input to parse delimited text       representing the data for the implementing class and initializes the
> >         objects instance variables with the parsed values. The delimiter to use
> >         must be specified for the Scanner input before calling this method.>

I can not figure out how to create the toObject part.  The problem I am having is implementing it in other methods.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Explorer extends Occupant{

  private String name;
  private Maze maze;

  public Explorer(Square location, Maze maze, String name){
    super(location);
    this.maze = maze;
    this.name = name;
    maze.lookAround(location);
  }

  public Explorer (Maze maze){
    this.maze = new Maze();
  }

  public String name(){
    return name;
  }

  public void move(int key){
    Square sq = location();

   if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP || KeyEvent.VK_KP_UP == key){
      if(!sq.wall(Square.UP)){
        this.moveTo(maze.getSquare(sq.row()-1, sq.col()));
      }
    }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT || KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT == key){
      if(!sq.wall(Square.RIGHT)){
        this.moveTo(maze.getSquare(sq.row(), sq.col()+1));
      }
    }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN || KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN == key){
      if(!sq.wall(Square.DOWN)){
        this.moveTo(maze.getSquare(sq.row()+1, sq.col()));
      }
    }
    else if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT || KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT == key){
      if(!sq.wall(Square.LEFT)){
        this.moveTo(maze.getSquare(sq.row(), sq.col()-1));
      }
    }
  }

  public void moveTo(Square s){
    super.moveTo(s);
    s.enter();
    maze.lookAround(s);
  }

  public void toObject(Scanner input){
    super.toObject(input);
    this.name = input.next();

  }

public String toText(char delimiter){
    String x = this.getClass().getName() + delimiter + location().row()  + delimiter + location().col() + delimiter + name;
    return x;
  }

}
```

I am not sure how to use the toObject method.  If I am doing it right, should I try and pass maze through it?  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The assignment is very poorly specified.  If you are creating an _interface_ then you don't have to implement anything.  An interface cannot have concrete methods (well in Java 8 they can have default methods, but that's different).  The name `toObject` is badly named in that it is semantically the opposite of other `toXxx` methods.  Those methods, like `toString()` operate on `this` and _return_ the value of `this` converted to another form.  The specification of `toObject` operates in the other direction.  Finally, given the definition of `toObject`, it makes sense... (continued)

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that.  It is supposed to be the opposite.  Basically it is supposed to reverse the toString() method.

Comment: ... only as a _static_ method of a class since it is intended to deserialize the object from external storage.  It should be defined something like `public static Explorer deserialize(Scanner s)` instead, and should return a newly constructed and initialized instance.  Or maybe `public static Explorer fromString(Scanner s)`.  Consider also that to use it specified you have to construct an instance and then completely overwrite that instance's internal state.  This is an anti-pattern in pretty much any language, and would be horrible code-smell in any commercial software.

Comment: @JimGarrison I think it's supposed to modify the instance in place, pretty much like Externalizable.readExternal() does (at least that's how I read the requirement). As for the naming, there's definitely room for improvement there...

Comment: I don't see the `toText()` method in your code sample. I have a strong feeling that, once you try to implement that, you'll get a better understanding on how you're supposed to use that scanner in the `toObject()` method.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu Added it, am I supposed to be changing say location().row() to an object?

Comment: @SailorJerry You need to implement the memento pattern using a mere string as memento (as @JimGarrison mentioned, the requirement itself is at least arguable). Keep in mind that you'll have to be able to handle *any delimiter*, so you need to escape that char in `toText` and unescape it in `toObject`. Read more about memento here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern